# ¿Cómo recuperar commits borrados en el repositorio remoto?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Alguien sabe como hago para recuperar commits que he borrado por error al haber utilizado `git push --force`? De ser así que comandos debo utilizar?

Utilize `git push --force` porque no me dejaba subir un archivo.

Comment: ¿Tienes aún esos commits en alguna copia local del repositorio? Si crees que no, mira a ver si con `git reflog` puedes obtener sus hashes y volver a ellos con `git checkout`. Si es así, podría haber forma de recuperarlo, pero habría que pensar bien cómo. No parece sencillo. Si no tienes copias locales de los commits olvídalo...

Answer (score 2):

Podes utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
git reflog
```

Te va a mostrar todos los commit que realizaste sin importar si los borraste o no.

Para moverte al commit que quieras usa alguno de estos comandos:

```
git reset --mixed y acá pegas el numero de hash del commit
```

(Este comando te guarda los cambios del commit que estas para que no los pierdas, para después poder guardarlos de nuevo)

```
git reset --hard y y acá pegas el numero de hash del commit
```

(Este te cambia al commit que le indicaste pero te borra los cambios que tengas)
-Cuando tires el comando git reflog al lado de los commit te va aparecer algo asi (bb85423), a eso me refiero con el numero de hash.

Answer (score 0):

Yo prefiero dentro de lo posible evitar usar `git reset` ya que es un poco destructivo si se usa sin cuidados. Lo que te recomiendo es ejecutar un `git reflog` buscar el hash del commit que deseas recuperar. Luego te posicionas en la rama a la que quieres agregar ese commit con un `git checkout` y le haces un `git merge`.